# How to get the AWS SQS metrics with python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-cloudwatch

At the moment we use the package `boto` to get queue messages and then, do some processing. The relevant code is:

```
from boto.sqs.message import RawMessage
import boto.sqs
import boto.sns
import json

conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region(
    "us-west-1",
    aws_access_key_id="XXXXXXX",
    aws_secret_access_key="XXXXXXX")
q=conn.get_queue('queueName')
q.set_message_class(RawMessage)
res=q.get_messages(10,wait_time_seconds=1)
....
```

and the rest is just processing code (not important for the question). This code works perfectly.

I was wondering if there is a way to, from python, get the metrics of the queue, for example, `NumberOfMessagesSent`.

Based on this post [get metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383809/how-do-i-get-the-most-recent-cloudwatch-metric-data-for-an-instance-using-boto) and the [CloudWatch](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/cloudwatch.html) website, I thought there might be something like

```
conn = boto.sqs.cloudwatch.connect_to_region()
```

from which I could do

```
conn.get_metric_statistics()
```

but it does not seem to be the case (unless I have missed something).

I have found this very nice piece of [code](https://gist.github.com/kjoconnor/3150204). But I was wondering if there is something "better" (or a more concise alternative) within `boto.sqs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the following attributes if you call `q.get_attributes()`

> ApproximateNumberOfMessages, ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible,
>   VisibilityTimeout, CreatedTimestamp, LastModifiedTimestamp, Policy
>   ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds

For things like `NumberOfMessagesSent` you will need to query CloudWatch for the data SQS logs there. The code you linked looks like the proper way to query CloudWatch metrics using boto.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

Also, in case anyone finds it useful, we found a similar way to the one in the [code](https://gist.github.com/kjoconnor/3150204) I linked, but perhaps a little bit more concise.

```
import boto
import datetime
conn = boto.connect_cloudwatch(aws_access_key_id="xxx",aws_secret_access_key="xxx")
conn.get_metric_statistics(
        300,
        datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=300),
        datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
        'ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible',
        'AWS/SQS',
        'Average',
        dimensions={'QueueName':['Myqueuename']}
   )
```